# why visual studio 2010 DataRepeater does not display images

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2010, downgrade, datarepeater

since one month I stacked in the Data Repeater of Visual Studio 2010, trying to display images of a table, but no result. at last some developers told me that visual studio 2010's Power Pack has bug, so they told me to try it with Visual Studio 2008, which I did, worked perfectly.

Now my problem is, either I should downgrade my project to 2008, which I tried according to some guidance by developers. but didn't worked for me. because that sort of conversion works for those who developed their projects in 2008, but mistakenly opened it in 2010.

The other way I may have is to look for some newer version of Visual Studio in which this power pack problem hopefully solved.

Does anyone have any idea, how to solve this problem? and one thing else, is this problem solved in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013? thanks in advance.

Comment: There have been several releases of the PowerPack controls.  The one released around early 2010 had at least one critical bug I know of.  Maybe you need [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169), that's a guess.

Comment: I already installed the 3.0, but when I select the 9.0, the data repeater itself disappears, until I should the 10.0 again. yes I tried this one too.

Comment: Hmm, don't add that to your question, it is an irrelevant detail.  Right-click the toolbox, select "Choose items".

Comment: Choose Items, that was the same thing I did, do you mean I shouldn't select version 9.0.0.0 ?